# Can jQ assess the code itself and execute based on findings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is such function even possible using jQ...

- look through code, find all vars/functions which name contains 'blah'
- make array of such var names
- as the code in each ..._blah var/function is executed, last line of it would declare that the code has been processed, this would then report back to the array matching each corresponding element in array with a 'completed' kind of a value
- once all ..._blah var names have been matched (i.e. all code in them has been executed), the function would return 'all ok' and then execute whatever as result

It's kind of like building a custom event listener I guess but listening to the code execution itself

Comment: By 'the code' do you mean the JavaScript running on the page?

Comment: yes, can it evaluate itself